# Does the readoption of the cosmological constant apply across all models of GR?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

I'm currently reading about cosmology, and the reintroduction of the cosmological constant, Lambda, into the field equations, to give a more accurate model for cosmology.

My question is this:

If it is now commonly thought that the field equations with Lambda provide the most accurate model for cosmology, is it 
(i) also thought the field equations with Lambda provide the most accurate model for general relativity, hence the most accurate model for the description of planetary orbits and other local phenomena?
or is it 
(ii) thought that we must use different field equations when modelling the cosmos as those used for modelling local phenomena?

If the answer is (i), then does the Schwarzschild model agree with the field equations containing Lambda, or is this model outdated?

Many Thanks,
A (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the scale of the Solar System the cosmological constant makes a negligable difference, and the Schwarzschild metric remains an excellent description of the geometry. If you want to include the effect of the cosmological constant this can be done by using the [Schwarzschild-de Sitter metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric) instead.